# How to change color of text when it is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the color of text when clicking on it. Can anybody let me know why this code isnt working?

```
<html>
<body>
 <center>
  <div id="web" style="color:black" onclick="changeformat(this.id)"> Web </div>
  <div id="img" style="color:blue" onclick="changeformat(this.id)"> Images </div>
  <div id="news" style="color:blue" onclick="changeformat(this.id)"> News </div>
 </center>
</body>
</html>

<script>
function changeformat(type)
    {
    document.getElementById('web').style = "color:blue;";
    document.getElementById('img').style = "color:blue";
    document.getElementById('news').style = "color:blue";  
    document.getElementById(type).style = "color:black";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Derek: yes i saw it 10s too late :D

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eUMDL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This, It will work. The correct way to change the color is using: document.getElementById(id).style.color

```
<html>
<body>
 <center>
   <div id="web" style="color:black" onclick="changeformat(this.id)"> Web </div>
   <div id="img" style="color:blue" onclick="changeformat(this.id)"> Images </div>
   <div id="news" style="color:blue" onclick="changeformat(this.id)"> News </div>
 </center>
</body>
</html>

<script>
function changeformat(type)
{
document.getElementById('web').style.color = "blue";
    document.getElementById('img').style.color = "blue";
    document.getElementById('news').style.color = "blue";  
    document.getElementById(type).style.color = "black";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it, use `element.style.color`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vWE6v/)

```
function changeformat(type) {
    document.getElementById('web').style.color = "blue;";
    document.getElementById('img').style.color = "blue";
    document.getElementById('news').style.color = "blue";  
    document.getElementById(type).style.color = "black";
}
```

---

As Derek points out you can also use `element.setAttribute()`, this will override other inline styles that are already set on the element though.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/V378R/)

```
function changeformat(type) {
    document.getElementById('web').setAttribute("style", "color:blue;");
    document.getElementById('img').setAttribute("style", "color:blue");
    document.getElementById('news').setAttribute("style", "color:blue");
    document.getElementById(type).setAttribute("style", "color:black");
}
```

Comment: Side note: If you really want to change the color by doing "color: blue", you can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/V378R/

Comment: `document.getElementById('web')` seems to be null.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="web" style="color:black" onclick="changeformat(this)"> Web </div>
<div id="img" style="color:blue" onclick="changeformat(this)"> Images </div>
<div id="news" style="color:blue" onclick="changeformat(this)"> News </div>

function changeformat(element) {
    var elements = ['web', 'img', 'news'];
    for( var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++  ) {
        document.getElementById( elements[i] ).style.color = 'blue';
    }
    element.style.color = "black";
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KqNts/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the color this way:

```
//element.style.CSSProperty = Value;
  ele.style.color = "blue";
```

An optimized version:

```
<div id="web" style="color:black" onclick="changeformat(event)"> Web </div>

function changeformat(e){
    var eles = document.querySelectorAll("div");
    for(var i = 0 ; i < eles.length; i++){
        eles[i].style.color = "blue";
    }
    e.target.style.color = "black";
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/V378R/2/

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
function changeformat(type)
    {
    document.getElementById('web').style.color = 'green'; 
    document.getElementById('img').style.color = 'pink'; 
    document.getElementById('news').style.color = 'red'; 
    document.getElementById(type).style.color = "black";
    }
```